Multiple re-renders issue when updating loading state on parent component in React
I have a parent component which has a isLoading useState and read params from the URL and pass them to child component:
export function MainUserDetails() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const params = useParams();
  const userId = params.userId as string;

  const handleLoadingStateChanged = React.useCallback((loading: boolean) => {
    setIsLoading(loading);
  }, []);

  const MemoizedUserDetailsForm = React.useMemo(
    () => <UserDetailsForm userId={userId} onLoadingStateChanged={handleLoadingStateChanged} />,
    [userId, handleLoadingStateChanged]
  );

  return (
    <Stack spacing={4}>
      <Stack direction={{ xs: 'column', sm: 'row' }} spacing={3} sx={{ alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
        <Box sx={{ flex: '1 1 auto' }}>
          <Typography variant="h4">User Details</Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>{isLoading && <CircularProgress />}</Box>
      </Stack>
      {isLoading ? <Skeleton variant="rounded" height={500} /> : <>{MemoizedUserDetailsForm}</>}
    </Stack>
  );
}

In my child component inside useEffect I am fetching the component's data and the useEffect has a dependencies of the userId (which is being send from the parent component):
  React.useEffect(() => {

    const fetchBusinesses = async () => {
      try {
        const businesses = await getBusinesses(businessFilters);
        if (businesses.status === 'success') {
          setBusinesses(businesses.data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`[UserDetailsForm/#fetchBusinesses]: Failed to fetch businesses:`, error);
      }
    }

    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (userId) {
        onLoadingStateChanged?.(true);
        await fetchBusinesses();
        onLoadingStateChanged?.(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();

  }, [userId]);

My problem is that in this way, one of the components (I guess it's the parent one) is re-renders endlessly, when commenting out the onLoadingStateChanged from the fetchData function, it downloads the data once and everything is working fine.
I already changed the onLoadingStateChanged to use memoize function and also now the whole UserDetailsForm is memoize, but still the problem persists.
How can I overcome this problem?
